# Четвертьложки или четверть ложки

Tags: орфография

Можете сказать, мудрые, как правильно?

1. Четвертьложки мёда; четвертьногтя, четвертьежа, четвертьванны;
2. Четверть ложки мёда; четверть ногтя, четверть ежа, четверть ванны.

Comment: четверть не полу, зачем её слитно писать? четвероложка - может быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однозначно раздельно:

***Четверть ложки мёда***,

***Четверть ногтя***,

***Четверть ежа***,

***Четверть ванны***.

Во-первых — таких слов не существует и нет в словарях, а во-вторых — между ними можно задать вопрос или же поставить прилагательное, как-то:

***Четверть (чего?) ложки мёда***,

***Четверть (чего?) ногтя***,

***Четверть (кого?) ежа***,

***Четверть (чего?) ванны***;

***Четверть (алюминиевой) ложки мёда***,

***Четверть (человеческого) ногтя***,

***Четверть (африканского) ежа***,

***Четверть (чугунной) ванны***.

Можем, например, взять слово *четвертьфинал*: ни вопрос не задается, ни прилагательное не ставится. А если *четверть финала*, то и то и то сделать можно. **Но!** *Начало (чего?) четвертьфинала* — не *начало четверти (чего?) финала*.

Comment: *Как то* — по современным правилам, то бишь РАН, но не по Розенталю — пишется бездефисно перед перечислением, сэр.